# Copy values from frozen column to next visible column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a simple button in excel that will find the current column after the frozen column. I then want to write my values form B1 - B4 (B is the frozen column) to whatever column is after the frozen column.

So for an example. B is frozen now i scroll to the next column is G. If i click the button it must copy the value from b1 to g1. If i then continue scrolling till I am at column k it must take the value from b1 and copy it to k1.

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim value1 As Double
Dim value2 As Double
Dim value3 As Double
Dim value4 As Double

value1 = Cells(1, "B").Value
value2 = Cells(2, "B").Value
value3 = Cells(3, "B").Value
value4 = Cells(4, "B").Value

Cells(1, "C").Value = value1
Cells(2, "C").Value = value2
Cells(3, "C").Value = value3
Cells(4, "C").Value = value4

End Sub
```

As you can see currently it is hardcoded to copy to column C. So ideally i would want to be able to get a variable that knows what the next column would be and replace c with that.

Theoretically the column letter I need will always be the 3rd visible column if that is of any help. Please keep in mind I have never coded in VB or excel and would appreciate any help. I have looked at some examples but all of them was over complicated and I could not really understand what is going on. All help will be appreciated greatly.

Here is two pictures that might also explain what I need.

[image: First Image]

f i click the button this is the result.

I[image: Second image]

So if i know scroll to column k and press the button it should copy it to column K.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Button_2_Click()    

Dim value1 As Double  
Dim value2 As Double
Dim value3 As Double
Dim value4 As Double
Dim lastFrozenCol as Integer
Dim firstCol as Integer

lastFrozenCol = ActiveWindow.Panes(1).VisibleRange.Columns.Count   
firstCol = ActiveWindow.Panes(2).VisibleRange.Column

value1 = Cells(1, lastFrozenCol).Value
value2 = Cells(2, lastFrozenCol).Value
value3 = Cells(3, lastFrozenCol).Value
value4 = Cells(4, lastFrozenCol).Value

Cells(1, firstCol).Value = value1
Cells(2, firstCol).Value = value2
Cells(3, firstCol).Value = value3
Cells(4, firstCol).Value = value4

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to have worked. Not completely what i wanted there was no need for lastFrozenRowCol. Removed that and hardcoded it to b and it worked thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your posting correctly you want to copy the values from a hardcoded range (`B1:B4`) into the cells in and under your current active cell when you click the button. Please consider the following solution:

EDITED:

```
Sub Button2_Click()

    Cells(1, ActiveWindow.SplitColumn + 1).value2 = Cells(1, 2).value2
    Cells(2, ActiveWindow.SplitColumn + 1).value2 = Cells(2, 2).value2
    Cells(3, ActiveWindow.SplitColumn + 1).value2 = Cells(3, 2).value2
    Cells(4, ActiveWindow.SplitColumn + 1).value2 = Cells(4, 2).value2

End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Hi, yes you are partially understanding. However I only want to copy the values from (B1:B4) to the column right after B. So if i srolled and the column is A  | B | E then the values from (B1:B4) must copy only to (E1:E4) and not to (C1:C4) and (D1:D4). Also it must not be dependent on the active cell at all.

Comment: I will try your solution later thank you very much. rwilson solution slightly modified was what i was looking for but thank you for your help.